# add location header to Spring MVC's POST response?

Tags: java, rest, http, spring-mvc, post

My `Spring Boot` 1.4 application has this `POST` HTTP Method to create a resource. As a requirement, it should spit a location header specifying the URL of the newly created resource: [RFC 9110 HTTP Semantics - Method Definitions](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-method-definitions). I am just wondering if there is any good way to do it than manually constructing the URL and adding it to the response.

Any helps/clues are deeply appreciated

Comment: You can use `ControllerLinkBuilder` from Spring Data REST, but it has its shortcomings.

Answer (score 53):

This exact scenario is demonstrated in the [Building REST Services with Spring Guide](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/).

Once you have persisted your new entity, in your controller you can use the below:

```
URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder
                    .fromCurrentRequest()
                    .path("/{id}")
                    .buildAndExpand(newEntity.getId())
                    .toUri();
```

You can then add this to your response using [ResponseEntity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) as below:

```
ResponseEntity.created(location).build()
```

or

```
ResponseEntity.status(CREATED).header(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, location).build()
```

The latter expects a string so you can use `toUriString()` on the uri builder instead of `toUri()`.

Comment: Should'nt the URI be built on the service layer?

Comment: @AlGrant I would say no because the URI is related the the HTTP endpoint and therefore I would encapsulate all work relating to it in the controller.

Your service could be called from multiple places e.g. perhaps a terminal interface in which case the URI may not be relevant.

It would depend on the architecture and use cases of your particular system though.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use `UriComponentsBuilder`. You can inject it right into a controller method:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE })
public ResponseEntity<Void> addCustomer(
          UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder, 
          @RequestBody CustomerRequest customerRequest ){

        final long customerId = customerService.addCustomer(customerRequest)

        UriComponents uriComponents =
                uriComponentsBuilder.path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(customerId);

        return ResponseEntity.created(uriComponents.toUri()).build();
}
```

Take note that the following will not compute the current request path. You will need to add it manually (or I might be missing something).

ex:

```
UriComponents uriComponents =
       uriComponentsBuilder.path("CURRENT_REQUEST_PATH/{id}")
       .buildAndExpand(customerId);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 @Autowired 
 private UserService service;

 @PostMapping("/users")
 public ResponseEntity<Object> createUser(@RequestBody User user)
  {
    User myUser = service.save(user);
    URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder
                .fromCurrentRequest()
                .path("/{id}")
                .buildAndExpand(myUser.getId())
                .toUri();

    ResponseEntity.created(location).build()
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52024684/6950859) pointed me in the right direction, but my create entity endpoint path was slightly different from the path where the saved entity was stored.

I was able to use `fromCurrentRequest()` and `replacePath("new path here")` like so:

```
URI uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest()
        .replacePath("/customer/{id}/fat")
        .buildAndExpand(savedCustomer.getCustomerId())
        .toUri();

return ResponseEntity.created(uri).build();
```