# How to return CREATED status (201 HTTP) in ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, http, spring-mvc

There is a `Spring-MVC` application. In controllers, when returning the results of methods, I return via `ResponseEntity<>`. On success, I return (`200` statutes) the `OK`-method. But when creating something, I would like to return the `CREATED`-method (`201` status). I just can’t understand what kind of `URL` to ask in parentheses when calling through `CREATED`. How can this be implemented?

Now I have such an implementation:

```java
@PostMapping("/create/dish")
    ResponseEntity<Dish> createDish(@Valid @RequestBody DishDTO dishDTO) {

        return ResponseEntity.ok(cookService.createDish(dishDTO.getDishName(), dishDTO.getAboutDish(), dishDTO.getDishType(),
                dishDTO.getCookingTime(), dishDTO.getWeight(),
                dishDTO.getDishCost(), dishDTO.getCooksId()));
    }
```

I want to remake it like this to make it work(now it not work):

```java
@PostMapping("/create/dish")
    ResponseEntity<Dish> createDish(@Valid @RequestBody DishDTO dishDTO) {

        return ResponseEntity.created(cookService.createDish(dishDTO.getDishName(), dishDTO.getAboutDish(), dishDTO.getDishType(),
                dishDTO.getCookingTime(), dishDTO.getWeight(),
                dishDTO.getDishCost(), dishDTO.getCooksId()));
    }
```

[image]

P.S. I don’t have a frontend at all. All through Swagger or PostMan.

Comment: The "Created" status is 201, not 203.

Comment: I'm change my question. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [add location header to Spring MVC's POST response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42546141/add-location-header-to-spring-mvcs-post-response)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just return this way:

```java
return new ResponseEntity<Dish>(cookService.createDish(...), HttpStatus.CREATED)
```

Making sure you have imported `org.springframework.http.HttpStatus`

Comment: Got error: The constructor ResponseEntity<Customer>(String, HttpStatus) is undefined

Comment: @devPrakash The first parameter must be, in your case, a `Customer`, not a `String`

Answer (score 9):

You can use

```
    ResponseEntity.created(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(savedObjectId).toUri()).build()
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to create a 201 (CREATED) response without a body, then use:

```
ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).build()
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
return new ResponseEntity(cookService.createDish(...), HttpStatus.CREATED);
```

Read more [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-entity)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to return 201 (Created) status you can also dispose of ResponseEntity and set @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED) for RestController method like this

```
@PostMapping("/create/dish")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED) 
Dish createDish(@Valid @RequestBody DishDTO dishDTO) {
    return cookService.createDish(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(status);
```