# How to return Http Status CREATED instead of OK

Tags: java, spring

I have no idea why but I'm not able to send http `created` instead of `ok` with my code.

Any help??

```
Optional<UserDTO> result = userService.save(userDTO);
return result.map(ResponseEntity::ok).orElseGet(() -> ResponseEntity.badRequest().build()); // This works
```

Doesn't work:

```
 Optional<UserDTO> result = userService.save(userDTO);
 return result.map(ResponseEntity::created).orElseGet(() -> ResponseEntity.badRequest().build()); //error Incompatible types: UserDTO is not convertible to URI
```

Comment: The use of that status code is to indicate that the resource has been created and you provide the Location of said resource in the response. See [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/201). To do what you want, look at this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62323734/how-to-return-created-status-201-http-in-responseentity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return CREATED status (201 HTTP) in ResponseEntity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62323734/how-to-return-created-status-201-http-in-responseentity)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html), the key difference is as follows:

- `ResponseEntity::ok` - returns "*the created **ResponseEntity***"
- `ResponseEntity::created` - returns "*the created **builder***"

So, you need an additional step with `created` and call `.build()` to get expected behavior.Something like:

```
  ...result.map(uri -> ResponseEntity.created(uri).build())...
```