# Spring MVC - returning DTO in response body for POST Request?

Tags: java, spring, rest, http, dto

I have the following controller `POST` method that creates a new meeting.

```
@PostMapping("/meetings")
ResponseEntity<Object> createMeeting(@RequestBody MeetingDTO meetingDTO) {

    meetingService.createMeeting(meetingDTO);
    return ResponseEntity.ok("created");
}
```

This is the service logic where I update my `Meeting` database entity using the `MeetingDTO`:

```
    public void createMeeting(MeetingDTO meetingDTO){

    Organiser organiser = personRepository.findById(meetingDTO.getPersonId())
            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("No Person with Id "
                    + meetingDTO.getPersonId()));

    Meeting meeting = new Meeting();
    meeting.setDate(meetingDTO.getDate());
    meeting.setTime(meetingDTO.getTime());
    meeting.setOrganiser(organiser);

    meetingRepository.save(meeting);
}
```

I am using `MeetingDTO` as the request body in my `POST` as I *do not* want to expose certain other fields within `Meeting` Entity.

Is this a correct use of the `DTO` pattern? Should I be returning the DTO again in the `POST` response in the response body?

Comment: Ideally the POST response should be HTTP Status Code of 201 and response should contain the created resource. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62323734/how-to-return-created-status-201-http-in-responseentity for similar query. And refer to https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html for design guideline on RESTFul Web Services.

Comment: do you mean the response should contain the entity? I thought the entity should not be exposed

Comment: The response should be DTO, not entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct usage of DTO and Entity. Domain model shouldn't be exposed to outside world.
[image]
Here is good article on this topic: [Understanding Spring Web Application Architecture: The Classic Way](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/software-development/design/understanding-spring-web-application-architecture-the-classic-way/)