# ResponseEntity does not return the desired result

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

If I run the following method, I don't get a ResponseEntity back with my defined Response. All I see in Postman are two empty curly brackets. But the println shows me that everything is there.

```
@PostMapping
fun createUser(@RequestBody user:User): ResponseEntity<HttpResponse>{

    val newUser = userService.saveUser(user)


    val res_ = HttpResponse(
        timestamp = LocalDateTime.now().toString(),
        daten = mapOf("user" to newUser),
        message = "User created",
        status = HttpStatus.CREATED,
        statusCode = HttpStatus.CREATED.value(),
    )

    println(res_.toString())

    return ResponseEntity.created(URI.create("")).body(
        res_
    )
}
```

HttpResponse.kt:

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)
open class HttpResponse (

protected var timestamp:String?= LocalDateTime.now().toString(),
protected var statusCode:Int?=null,
protected var status: HttpStatus? = null,
protected var message:String?="",
protected var developerMessage:String="",
protected var path:String="",
protected var requestMethod:String = "",
protected var daten:Map<Any,Any>

)
```

Comment: why are you using `Lombok` with Kotlin? Why not use `data class` instead of `@Data` ?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

As described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62323981/14436662 you can simply use the following:

```
return ResponseEntity(res_, HttpStatus.CREATED)
```

**Created HTTP status**

The HTTP status created usually tells the requesting client that there is a new resource at the same location where the request went to or there is a location inside the *Location* header. Spring assumes that you're following those standards. Therefore, the *created* method of the *ResponseEntity* will not include any body.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/201 for more information about the created.