# Spring Boot REST API : Returning status code of ResponseEntity?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, http, spring-mvc

I use the following approach in my Spring Boot REST API controller and in here, I generally return `ResponseEntity.ok()` as I also want to pass returned data to the client.

However, I want to return proper statuses based on the operations. For example, after creating a record, I should use `ResponseEntity.created()`, and so on. I tried to use it, but it just takes `URI location` as a parameter and I am not sure about the folowing points:

**1)** How should I return create, edit and delete requests using `ResponseEntity` in Spring Boot apps properly?

**2)** I am not sure how to return the id of the created record or some data of the created record to the client by using `ResponseEntity.created()`.

```
@PostMapping("/categories")
public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<CommandResponse>> create(
            @Valid @RequestBody CategoryRequest request) {
        CommandResponse response = categoryService.create(request);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(
        new ApiResponse<>(Instant.now(clock).toEpochMilli(), SUCCESS, response));
}
```

I also use a custom `ApiResponse` class to wrap the response with necessary info.

Note: I also implemented a Global Exception Handler using `@RestControllerAdvice`. I just want to use and return correct request type for POST, PUT and DELETE besides GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the static method **status** to personalize your http status.
Ex:

```
ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED).build();
```

with a body :

```
ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("a message");
ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("a message");
```

As a rule of thumb the http code I use the standard REST operations (POST,PUT,GET,DELETE)

- POST=> HttpCode 201 (CREATED)
- PUT, GET => HttpCode 200 (OK)
- DELETE => HttpCode 204 (NO_CONTENT)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I would prefer using like `ResponseEntity.accepted()`. On the other hand, should I use `ok()` or `accepted()` for PUT and DELETE?

Comment: Are you sure that `PUT => HttpCode 201 (CREATED)` ?

Comment: @devx Sorry I inverted the verb, I edited my answer, the http code describe the intention of your server. I would use it when the request is OK but there are many things to do again or the processing is continuing in the background.

Comment: @devx I encourage you to look for the mozilla doc : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/202

Comment: What about URI parameter? Should URI point to the GET method to access newly created object with its id? Like /categories/100 ? Or the full path ? Any example pls with URI (using ResponseEntity.created())

Comment: I checked that page, but it conflicts with your suggestions. GET --> Ok, POST --> Created, PUT --> NoContent, DELETE --> ???

Comment: I use the code for the meaning I want to convey in a rest service. for exemple I deleted something and I have nothing to return in the body so I return a 204 http code, some prefer to stick to 200.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252193/discussion-between-kowlown-and-devx).

Answer (score 1):

`ResponseEntity.created()` returns a builder object which lets you modify response accordingly to your needs (take a look at a sample below). By default this URI parameter should point to api method which lets you read that method (including id). Those methods will set the response code automatically created(201), ok(200), but if you do need to modify it you may annotate the method with @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.XXX).

i.e.

```
ResponseEntity.created(uriToTheCreatedObject)
  .body(id)
```

If you removing you may return just `ResponseEntity.ok()`,

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, actually I do not want to use `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.XXX)` and would prefer `ResponseEntity.statusCode()`. In this case, I think we can use `ResponseEntity.created()`, etc to return a proper status code and by using the Builder object, we can add some data to the response as in `ResponseEntity.ok()`. Is that true?

Comment: And, could you please post some proper usage examples for PUT and DELETE? I am also  confused about the URI parameter. What is that parameter? `uriToTheCreatedObject` ?

Comment: Yes, it is true. The URI param should point directly to your method. Considering you have an CRUD API, then you have also some method which is intended to read objects. So you should put there a path to it like http://myserver.com/api/command-responses/{id_of_the_created_object.  Regarding the question from the first comment - you're perfectly right! you may use it exactly like ResponseEntity.ok()

Comment: For both PUT/DELETE i'd return ResponseEntity.accepted(), or even ResponseEntity.ok(). There are no separate status codes for deleting / modifying actions so above ones are okey.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I could not understand URI and how to provide it to my `ResponseEntity.created()` method. Could you post an example pls? I could not find any proper usage on the web also :(

Comment: Do you mean that URI should point the GET method to access newly created object with its id? Like `/categories/100` ? Or the full path ? Any example pls?

Comment: Hi @devx, you need to add full path. you may refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/52024684/2879245 in order to find out how to create one.

Answer (score 0):

Each API Endpoint should return one HttpStatus in success response. Normally, it will be 2xx status code
For your case, you can return HttpStatus.ok like this

```
  @PostMapping("/categories")
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
  public ApiResponse<CommandResponse> create(@Valid @RequestBody CategoryRequest request) {
    CommandResponse response = categoryService.create(request);
    return new ApiResponse<>(Instant.now(clock).toEpochMilli(), SUCCESS, response);
  }
```

In the case of failure response, you had @RestControllerAdvice already, each of exception will be handled and return with corresponding HttpStatus code, and better have one generic exception handler to avoid breaking the request context thread like this

```
  @ResponseBody
  @ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
  public void handleException(Throwable ex) {
    log.error("Internal Server Error", ex);
  }
```

Comment: need to remove @ResponseBody in my `public void handleException`